# Cannot query SimpleDB using ::sdb/id using clojure rummage library

Tags: clojure, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to query Amazon SimpleDB using the [clojure rummage](https://github.com/cemerick/rummage) library. I am successfully able to query my database using fields other than the primary key (itemName) for instance the following query returns a list of records:

```
(db/query-event client '{select * from dev where (= :benchmark_id "abcd")})
```

However I seem to be unable to do the same thing for the primary id field, where the below query returns nil and I know that there are records in the database that match this query.

```
(db/query-event client '{select * from dev where (> ::sdb/id "1421284428631")})
```

Comment: Can you compare amazon simple db keys with ">" and "<"?

Comment: @ordnungswidrig According to the rummage test suite you can - https://github.com/cemerick/rummage/blob/master/src/test/clojure/cemerick/rummage/query_test.clj#L103

Comment: @ordnungswidrig Also I believe being able to compare keys this way is important for paging the results of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query:

```
(db/query-event client '{select itemName() from `dev` where (> :: itemName() "1421284428631")})
```